# Adding indicator column to table based on having two consecutive days within group

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I need to add a logic that helps me to flag the first of two consecutive days as 1 and the second day as 0 grouped by a column (test). If a test (a) has three consecutive days then the third should start with 1 again etc.

Example table would be like following with new col being the column I need.

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      test           |     test_date    |      new col        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      a              |     1/1/2020     |      1              |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      a              |     1/2/2020     |      0              |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      a              |     1/3/2020     |      1              |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      b              |     1/1/2020     |      1              |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      b              |     1/2/2020     |      0              |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      b              |     1/15/2020    |      1              |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

As it seems to be some gaps-and-islands problem and I assume some windows function approach should get me there.

I tried something like following to get the consecutive part but struggle with the indicator column.

```
Select 
test, 
test_date,
grp_var = dateadd(day, 
                 -row_number() over (partition by test order by test_date), test_date)    
from 
my_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does read as a gaps-and-island problem. I would recommend using the difference between `row_number()` and the date to generate the groups, and then arithmetic:

```
select
    test,
    test_date, 
    row_number() over(  
        partition by test, dateadd(day, -rn, test_date)
        order by test_date
    ) % 2 new_col
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by test order by test_date) rn
    from mytable t
) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c3a2f5d47523f37801023ae6beed1dbd)**:

```
test | test_date  | new_col
:--- | :--------- | ------:
a    | 2020-01-01 |       1
a    | 2020-01-02 |       0
a    | 2020-01-03 |       1
b    | 2020-01-01 |       1
b    | 2020-01-02 |       0
b    | 2020-01-15 |       1
```